# Poetry Problems

Tags: poetry

> O western orb sailing the heaven,
>
> Now I know what you must have meant **as a month since I walk’d**,
>
> As I walk’d in silence the transparent shadowy night,
>
> As I saw you had something to tell as you bent to me night after
>   night,
>
> As you droop’d from the sky **low down** as if to my side, (while the
>   other stars all look’d on,)
>
> As we wander’d together the solemn night, (for something I know not
>   what kept me from sleep,)
>
> As the night advanced, and I saw on the rim of the west how full you
>   were of woe,
>
> As I stood on the rising ground in the breeze in the cool transparent
>   night,
>
> As I watch’d where you pass’d and **was lost** in the netherward black of
>   the night,
>
> As my soul in its trouble dissatisfied sank, as where you sad orb,
>
> Concluded, dropt in the night, and was gone.

This is the section 8 of "When Lilacs Last in the Dooryard Bloom’d" by Walt Whitman. I have some problems:

1. What he means by **as a month since I walk’d** in second line?
2. The use of "low down" is just redundant?
3. "As I watch’d where you pass’d and was lost", if the subject is you, why he used "was"?

(First I asked these questions in literature stackexchange, but no one answered me. So please don't tell me to ask this kind of question on literature stackexchange.)

Comment: Generally, the interpretation of poetry is off-topic here, since it often uses vague imagery and strange metaphors (not to mention archaic terminology).  I would take "a month since I walked" to mean "a month since I left".

Comment: @HotLicks - "Now I know what you must have meant as a month since I left"? Does it make sense to you? The problem, I think, is about using "as" and "since" in a strange way.

Comment: @HotLicks Please read the answer of Colin Fine below. My questions are all about linguistic problems in general. I know that here is not a poetry forum. But my questions are all about linguistic problems, not poetical problems.

Comment: I don't see what the "linguistic problem" is with "a month since".  It's about a month since Thanksgiving -- this is common usage.

Comment: No here it means “ago”. It means “as a month ago”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since* is usually a conjunction in current English; but it can also be used as an adverb, meaning *ago*.

The OED gives definition 4:  "Ago; before now. With time specified, or preceded by *long*", and doesn't mark it as unusual;  but I would describe it as "archaic or dialectal". It is alive and well in Yorkshire where I live: you often hear things like *I saw him a month since*. But it is not common in standard English.

But the meaning here is clearly "as a month ago I walked".

Comment: That is it. You are so right.

Answer (score 1):

> The use of "low down" is just redundant?

I suppose so.

I would not say it is strikingly redundant -- it's a pretty natural way to express the thought.

> "As I watch’d where you pass’d and was lost", if the subject is you, why he used "was"?

Some dialects do this. Whitman was known to do this in other writings, for example in one poem in *Leaves of Grass* he wrote "Think of the time when you was not yet born!" He also used *were*, e.g. "Perhaps you have been on it since you were born, and did not know."

Some speakers use you/they *was* for the past and you/they *were* for the subjunctive consistently, but I don't believe that is a characteristic of Whitman's writing.

Comment: Thanks. Don't you have any suggestion for first problem?